# Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)): ActiveX and C# Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, com, activex

So, I am playing around with ActiveX and C# and ways how both of them can work together. the thing is I have hit the wall right in the beginning with mentioned error. Steps I have followed:

In VS2010 I selected MFC  ActiveX Control project. Then I added a method "SHORT Multiply( SHORT a, SHORT b);" by clicking the Add method option in the menu that pops when you right click _DProjectname under ProjectnameLib in solution explorer. The code for the method is as follows:

```
    SHORT CSampleProgramActivex01Ctrl::Multiply(SHORT a, SHORT b)
    {
      AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

     // TODO: Add your dispatch handler code here

     return ( a * b);
    }
```

Now I have created a simple C# console application that references the generated COM file and when I try to use the method, the application stops with the above mentioned error. I have searched the error on the internet but no clear solution is mentioned. Any help appreciated. If you guys want clarification, let me know.

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you have any idea why I am getting this error? I tried all different types of visual studio from VS6 to VS2010 but each time I am getting the same error. Do you by any chance have simple tutorial that creates .ocx file through MFC ActiveX wizard. I am asking this because the vendor has created .ocx through MFC ActiveX wizard and I am running into some other error in that ocx. So I am trying to create my own .ocx in the same way and simulate the problem that vendor is having. But before I go over there, I am hitting this error. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is considered as solving the problem or not but I found a workaround:

First instead of C# console application, I created C# windows form application. After creating the form, I have added the whole ocx as component in  the toolbox. You do this by right-clicking the Toolbox types in Toolbox menu. In the new menu, you click Choose Items. This pops up new menu and in that select the COM tab and in that check your COM component and the  COM component will be added to the Toolbox menu. Now drag and drop the component on the menu and you should be good to go.

This seems to be workaround that everybody is following. Not neat but that is the norm I think.

Comment: I would like to know other opinions.

Comment: You can also use tblimp / aximp command line utilities to generate the same two wrapper dll's as the generator does. Then Reference System.Windows.Forms.dll and you can instantiate your var ctrl = new AxSomeControl() and then ctrl.CreateControl(). So basically you can have console application with ocx but you'll need to reference WinForms .dll anyway.

Answer (score 1):

look at here: How to use an OLE control as an automation server in Visual C++
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146120/en-us