# Error when run activeX control in different computer

Tags: c#, activex

I've implement my activeX control in Delphi. I've build a c# application to embed it. It runs fine on my computer. After that, I copy and paste all c# solution with the my ocx file to another computer, register by regsrv32.exe succeed, add to COM components on visual studio toolbox, compile and run again. It consistently complains '

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

What's problem I'm dealing with? What may I do wrong?

Comment: Do you use WinForms? And have you added ocx control to Visual Studio Toolbox? Here is a thread with the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245723/catastrophic-failure-exception-from-hresult-0x8000ffff-e-unexpected-active

Comment: I've already read that thread. I've done exactly like that post, because I use Winform from the start, but it no helps.